# G=$(\Bbb Z^ \times_{14},·)$ Want to find orders of elements of this group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I know by the Euler function φ(14)=φ(7*2)=7*2(1-$(1/7)$)(1-$(1/2)$)=6.  So I know the order is 6 so there are 6 elements in this group.  However, I am not sure how to generate these elements.  I know $[1]$ is in this group since $[1]^{1}$=$[1]$ by definition of the order of an element.  However I am having trouble generating the other elements.  I know the element raised to a power must equal [1].  I know $[1]$=$[15]$=$[29]$=$[43]$=$[57]$ ..... but realistically I can't be doing this forever to find the other 5 elements.  How can I find these elements without having to do this.

Comment: Check the numbers that are relatively prime to $14$.

Comment: Which group do you denote $Z\times 14$?

Comment: @Bernard: Probably meant to be $\mathbb{Z}_{14}^{\times}$.

Comment: @RobertShore okay so these numbers are obviously [1],[3],[5],[9],[11],[13].  However I do need to find the orders of these elements.  How would I find these orders without doing the exhausting process I outlined in the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force is the way to start this problem. If you think a little before you multiply you will see that you never need to deal with large numbers. Here's a sample calculation (omitting the square braces):

$$
3^2 = 9, 3^3 = 9 \times 3 = 27 \equiv -1
$$

so $3^6 \equiv 1$. That means the order of $3$ is $6$. And finding this out tells you the order of $9$ (it must be $3$) and of $5 \equiv -9$, which will be $6$. You can finish without doing any more multiplication.

Informative, and not very exhausting. By coincidence I happened to start out with a class whose order was $6$. If in a larger example I was less lucky I'd still get lots of partial information. Then I'd pick an element I didn't know about and continue.

Comment: So this would mean the following: [13]=[-1] so [13]^{2}=[1] so the order of 13 is 2, and [11]=[-3] and [-3]^{2}=[9] so [11]^{6}=[1] and the order of 11 is 6?

Comment: The order of $[13]$ is $2$; the order of $[11]$ is $3$ [$11^3\equiv(-3)^3\equiv-27\equiv1\mod14]$

Answer (score 0):

Yoou only have to make the computations with the canonical representatives of the congruence classes. To shorten further the computations, you may use Lagrange's theorem, which tells ou they have order a divisor of $6$, and write these as 
$$\bar 1,\quad\bar 3,\quad\bar 5, \quad-\bar{1}=\bar{13},\quad-\bar 3=\bar{11}, \quad-\bar 5=\bar 9.$$
It is easy to check the order of $\bar 3$ is $6$, and the order of $-\bar 3$ is $3$. Also, $\bar 5^2=\bar{11}=-\bar 3$, so $\bar 5$ has order $6$, and similarly, you can check $-\bar 5$ has order $3$.